# NSTextView's adjustScroll method

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstextview, nsscrollview

I'm trying to implement typewriter scrolling in my Cocoa text editor, keeping the insertion point centered vertically in its scrollview.

Toward this end, I have subclassed `NSClipView` to provide a `scrollToPointWithoutConstraint` method, which scrolls the document to a specified point without calling `constrainScrollPoint`. This is necessary because for short documents the insertion point can't be centered unless we scroll beyond the document's bounds.

This seems reasonably straightforward so far and does what I want. The problem comes in when I try to scroll using the scroll bars. If I'm scrolled to the end of the document, such that part of the scroll view contains an area outside the document's bounds, trying to scroll up by a small increment causes the scroll view to jump, immediately clamping to the document's actual bounds.

I gather that I might need to subclass `NSTextView` and override the `adjustScroll` method; this is where my actual question begins. The `proposedVisibleRect` that is passed to `adjustScroll` already has its dimensions adjusted so that they lie within the document's actual bounds. Is there a way that I can change the value of `proposedVisibleRect` before `adjustScroll` is called? Alternatively, am I going about this entirely wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?